# Already forwarded by dispatcher - Access author through proxy with dispatcher author

Tags: java, aem, dispatcher, apache-modules

I am currently trying to get an author dispatcher connected to an AEM Author instance. So without further ado I configure ***server1*** with an author, try to access it through a browser ... works great. Then I configure the Author dispatcher on ***server2*** point it to ***server1*** ... try accessing it in a browser ... works great my author dispatcher serves pages and caches them perfectly.

Ok here comes the meat of this problem, I now configure an author on ***server3*** that lives behind a proxy and point the dispatcher on ***server2*** to  forward requests to ***server3***. So essentially the dispatcher author on ***server2*** would need to go through the proxy to get to the ***server3***. The proxy is correctly configured to forward requests to ***server3***, 100% about that. This is where my problem lives as it seems like the dispatcher is unable to do this. When I request a page on ***server3*** I get the following log message:

```
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] Found farm author for server2
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] checking [/]
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] request URL has no extension: /
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] cache-action for [/]: NONE
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] Connected to backend rend01 (server3)
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] Adding request header: Host
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] Adding request header: Cache-Control
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] Adding request header: Accept
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] Adding request header: Upgrade-Insecure-Requests
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] Adding request header: User-Agent
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] Adding request header: Accept-Encoding
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] Adding request header: Accept-Language
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] Adding request header: Cookie
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] Adding request header: X-Forwarded-Proto
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] Adding request header: X-B3-TraceId
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] Adding request header: X-B3-SpanId
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] Adding request header: X-B3-ParentSpanId
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] Adding request header: X-B3-Flags
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] Adding request header: Via
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] Adding request header: X-Forwarded-For
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] Adding request header: Server-Agent
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [I] [26731] Already forwarded by dispatcher (server2), declined.
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [I] [26731] "GET /" - - 0ms
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] response.status = 404
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] response.headers[Date] = "Wed, 11 May 2016 20:50:42 GMT"
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] response.headers[Content-Type] = "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] response.headers[Content-Encoding] = "gzip"
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [D] [26730] response.headers[Content-Length] = "180"
[Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [I] [26730] "GET /" 404 180 5ms
```

I have no clue as to why I can not access my author instance with a dispatcher author through a proxy.

Any thoughts or suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your proxy headers?

"proxy-authorization" "proxy-connection"

see at https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html :

```
/clientheaders
{
    "referer"
    "user-agent"
    "authorization"
    "from"
    "content-type"
    "content-length"
    "accept-charset"
    "accept-encoding"
    "accept-language"
    "accept"
    "host"
    "if-match"
    "if-none-match"
    "if-range"
    "if-unmodified-since"
    "max-forwards"
    "proxy-authorization"
    "proxy-connection"
    "range"
    "cookie"
    "cq-action"
    "cq-handle"
    "handle"
    "action"
    "cqstats"
    "PATH"
}
```

Comment: Also, this looks strange to me: [Wed May 11 20:50:42 2016] [I] [26731] Already forwarded by dispatcher (server2), declined.